# How to pinch zoom within finger point?

Tags: android, android-gesture

Right now I am using this code as custom layout in android studio. But the large problem is that when pinch-to-zoom, it will zoom into the point 0,0 ,instead of zooming into the finger point.

https://gist.github.com/anorth/9845602

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Forked the original gist and updated it, [view it here](https://gist.github.com/klarson2/4f737adf7f2577dc0fd09efb85eff3b1). It was a little more complex than I thought.  The default pivot point for scaling a view is the center of the view.  In order to make this work I had to set the view pivot to (0,0) and the adjust the translation for the pivot from the user's gesture.

---

I noticed in your `onScale()` override you are calling `scaleDetector.getScaleFactor()` but you are not calling `scaleDetector.getFocusX()` and `scaleDetector.getFocusy()`.  These methods tell you what the focal point of the pinch-zoom is.  You will have to call these methods and get this focal point (x,y) then do some calculations to figure out the translation required to keep that focal point.  You will have to work this into your `dx` and `dy` values so that the translation accounts for the focal point.

To calculate the translation, you would take the focal point and multiply the x and y values by the change in scale factor.  This tells you how far the point would move given focal point (0,0).  So you would subtract x(updated) from x(original) and y(updated) from y(original) to get that move vector.  Your translation values are the negated vector values. So:

```
scale(delta) = scaleDector.getScaleFactor() -- just the change, not the new scale factor
translation x = x(focal) - x(focal) * scale(delta)
translation y = y(focal) - y(focal) * scale(delta)
```

So obviously you would add these values to your `dx` and `dy` values for translation.

Comment: Don't real get what you mean. Could you example more detail. Because I am new in this so I don't real get what you are saying. Thank you

Comment: @KrisLarson : how about reset layout when double tap?

Comment: @abcd1234 Please post a new question for that

Comment: @KrisLarson could you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856089/how-to-distinguish-between-pinch-zoom-and-click-in-ontouchevent

Comment: @KrisLarson : can you help me with this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903531/android-custom-framelayout-to-zoom>

Comment: @abcd1234, all I did was change somebody's code to zoom from the gesture focus instead of from the view center, which was the request of this question.  The touch event handling logic in that code was not implemented very well for working with other touch components and it needs to be rewritten.  That's not trivial and it's actually a bit beyond my skill level right now.